# cocoapod openssl-ios-bitcode no longer installing

Tags: openssl, cocoapods

I have a project where I have been using openssl-ios-bitcode.  Was making some modifications to my pod file, and deleted the entry by accident.  After re-adding the entry, I'm finding that the pod will not reinstall.

There is a prepare_command,

```
 s.prepare_command = <<-CMD
    VERSION="1.0.2l"
    SDKVERSION=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version 2> /dev/null`
    MIN_SDKVERSION="7.0"
    BASEPATH="${PWD}"
    CURRENTPATH="${TMPDIR}/openssl"
    ARCHS="i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64"
    DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`
    mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}"
    mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin"
    cp "file.tgz" "${CURRENTPATH}/file.tgz"
    cd "${CURRENTPATH}"
    tar -xzf file.tgz
    cd "openssl-${VERSION}"
    for ARCH in ${ARCHS}
    do
      CONFIGURE_FOR="iphoneos-cross"
      if [ "${ARCH}" == "i386" ] || [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ] ;
      then
        PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
        if [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ] ;
        then
          CONFIGURE_FOR="darwin64-x86_64-cc"
        fi
      else
        sed -ie "s!static volatile sig_atomic_t intr_signal;!static volatile intr_signal;!" "crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c"
        PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
      fi
      export CROSS_TOP="${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer"
      export CROSS_SDK="${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}.sdk"
      echo "Building openssl-${VERSION} for ${PLATFORM} ${SDKVERSION} ${ARCH}"
      echo "Please stand by..."
      export CC="${DEVELOPER}/usr/bin/gcc -arch ${ARCH} -miphoneos-version-min=${MIN_SDKVERSION} -fembed-bitcode"
      mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk"
      LOG="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/build-openssl-${VERSION}.log"
      LIPO_LIBSSL="${LIPO_LIBSSL} ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/lib/libssl.a"
      LIPO_LIBCRYPTO="${LIPO_LIBCRYPTO} ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/lib/libcrypto.a"
      ./Configure ${CONFIGURE_FOR} --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk" > "${LOG}" 2>&1
      sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} !" "Makefile"
      make >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
      make all install_sw >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
      make clean >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
    done
    echo "Build library..."
    rm -rf "${BASEPATH}/lib/"
    mkdir -p "${BASEPATH}/lib/"
    lipo -create ${LIPO_LIBSSL}    -output "${BASEPATH}/lib/libssl.a"
    lipo -create ${LIPO_LIBCRYPTO} -output "${BASEPATH}/lib/libcrypto.a"
    echo "Copying headers..."
    rm -rf "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"
    mkdir -p "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"
    cp -RL "${CURRENTPATH}/openssl-${VERSION}/include/openssl" "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"
    cd "${BASEPATH}"
    echo "Building done."
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm -rf "${CURRENTPATH}"
    echo "Done."
  CMD
```

It generates the following error message: **cp: file.tgz: No such file or directory**

Thinking the following line is where it's failing:  **cp "file.tgz" "${CURRENTPATH}/file.tgz"**

I have run with --verbose turned on, and I can see that the file is getting downloaded, not sure where, but the curl command appears to show a successful download.

Any ideas on how to debug my issue?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to move forward.  The openssl-ios-bitcode pod I had been using has a prepare_command statement that assumes that the file downloaded from OpenSSL.org will remain a tar gz file when downloaded.

Seems that somewhere along the way, Cocoapods behaviour has changed, and the downloaded tar gz file is automatically exploded.  The prepare_command statement had to be updated to take this into account.

In the process of resolving this for myself, I have created my own [fork](https://github.com/DaveDude/OpenSSL-Pod), and [pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/openssl-ios-bitcode-ii).

Another side issue I ran into, is that examples for doing receipt validation on iOS rely on helper functions to get at the union inside of the pkcs7_st structure.  I have found some more recent examples of how to correct this in some blogs, and have copied these examples into a new repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/DaveDude/OpenSSL-Swift-Pod).  Had attempted to turn these helper functions into a separate pod - but couldn't get past some module issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for XCode 12.5**

openssl-ios-bitcode tries to use xcrun *- command line tools -* so that you should check the command line tools are selected or not from:

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools
```